# PowerBI Sum/IF/CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, powerbi-desktop

```
SUM(B.RefundedAmount) + SUM(CASE WHEN B.AccountTypeID = 2 AND B.TotalStake = B.TotalPayout THEN B.TotalPayout ELSE 0 END)
```

The following is the logic for SQL code that I need to convert into a new powerBI column/measure.

RefundedAmount, AccountTypeID, TotalStake and TotalPayout are all columns in the dataset. I'm struggling to wrap my head around the addition aspect along with the IF/CASE WHEN statement.

Does it only mean that IF (AccountTypeID = 2 AND TotalStake = TotalPayout) then we return RefundedAmount + TotalPayout, otherwise return 0?

Answer (score 0):

The measure always returns at least `RefundedAmount`, but if `AccountTypeID = 2` and `TotalStake = TotalPayout` then it returns the sum of `RefundedAmount` and `TotalPayout`.

The measure could be written in DAX as:

```
Measure := 
VAR _refund = SUM ( 'Table'[RefundedAmount] )
VAR _payout = 
SUMX ( 
    FILTER ( 
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[TotalPayout] = 'Table'[TotalStake] 
            && 'Table'[AccountTypeID] = 2
    ),
    'Table'[TotalPayout]
)
RETURN
_refund + _payout
```